# How to open external page in jQuery dialog box with javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have edit page which contains some javascript code for load datepicker and chosen dropdown. I'm opening that page in a dialog box . But the scripts on external page is now not working . please advice

Comment: Was this working? There are several wrong things here but I need to know if this is new and you are trying to make it work, or it was working and you broke it somehow?

Comment: @Christos Lytras :yes its not working as expect. edit.php form is loading inside dialog box. but datepicker and validations on edit.php is not workinng

Comment: Any console or HTTP errors at develpment tools (F12 > Console/NetWork)? Can you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40830724/edit) and include the whole `edit.php`?

Comment: @Christos Lytras : I've updated with whole edit.php. I'm not getting any console errors.  but when I inspect dialog box after loading. the scrpits which written inside edit.php is not showing. When edit.php worked perfectly when it open as separate page. but once I change query.js to open it with dialog box and ajax submit only above issue occurred. pls advice me

Comment: @Christos Lytras  : can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Yes, I can look at it a little bit later. Can you open a chat so we can talk there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129157/discussion-between-tharu-perera-and-christos-lytras).

Comment: @Christos Lytras ok sure